# Как сделать требуемую выборку на SQL из MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

```
+---------+-------------------+----------+----------------------------------+
| user_id | email             | name     | password                         |
+---------+-------------------+----------+----------------------------------+
|       1 | norm1@yandex.ru   | Myname12 | 6822a3b5cfbc960577018c42eb6166ed |
|       2 | newuser@yandex.ru | newuser  | 42f749ade7f9e195bf475f37a44cafcb |
+---------+-------------------+----------+----------------------------------+
```

Вот есть такая таблица и такая

```
+---------+---------------+---------------------+---------+
| post_id | title         | content             | user_id |
+---------+---------------+---------------------+---------+
|       1 | Какае-то инфа | Информация какае-то |       2 |
|       2 | Тест пост     | Проверка!           |       2 |
+---------+---------------+---------------------+---------+
```

Как сделать выборку, чтобы за раз получить все posts и name из таблицы users к каждому посту?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT p.*, u.name
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.user_id=p.user_id
```

Comment: 18 сек =)))

Comment: Ага, нужно провести конкурс на скорость ответа )))

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from postTable p left join userTable u on p.user_id = u.user_id
```